# How to find the index of the second largest value in an array

Tags: objective-c

Given this:

```
int areas[20];

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    areas[i] = detectedBlobs[i].getWidth() * detectedBlobs[i].getHeight();
}
```

I understand how to sort arrays and find the first, second, third, etc. largest values, but how can I find the index values associated with the first, second or third largest values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know how to find the largest value in a sorted array, the next step would be enumerate through unsorted array and compare each object with largest value if matches you can get the index of it! –